# Call method from a panel at another class(the method) that terminats current panel

Tags: java, swing, class, methods, jpanel

i have three classes {`FirstFrame, Login, Register`} ... there is a method in `FirstFrame` to change between `Logi` and `Register`

`FirstFrame` code :

```
public class FirstFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public FirstFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    changeTo(Login.class);        
}

public void changeTo(Class<?> c){
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    try {
        Object obj = c.newInstance();
        getContentPane().add((Component) obj);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("here");
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FirstFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FirstFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
}
```

In `Register` I have a button that stores data then go back to `Login`(supposedly)

It works great if I call from any button inside `FirstFrame`

The question here is how do I call `changeTo(Class<?> c)` from inside `Register`?

Comment: @peeskillet thanks for the hight lighting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to help you do the swapping as this is precisely what it is for.
2. Give the FirstFrame a public method that allows other classes the ability to swap.
3. Pass an instance of FirstFrame to the objects that need to call this method. This can be done via a constructor or setter method parameter.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FirstFrame extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = 300;
   private Login login = new Login(this);
   private Register register = new Register(this);
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

   public FirstFrame() {
      setLayout(cardLayout);
      add(login, Login.class.toString());
      add(register, Register.class.toString());
   }

   public void swapCards(String key) {
      cardLayout.show(this, key);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      FirstFrame mainPanel = new FirstFrame();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FirstFrame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SwapCardAction extends AbstractAction {
   private String key;
   private FirstFrame firstFrame;

   public SwapCardAction(String name, int mnemonic, String key,
         FirstFrame firstFrame) {
      super(name);
      this.key = key;
      this.firstFrame = firstFrame;
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      firstFrame.swapCards(key);
   }
}

class Register extends JPanel {

   public Register(final FirstFrame firstFrame) {
      setBackground(new Color(255, 200, 200));
      JButton gotToLoginBtn = new JButton(new SwapCardAction("Login",
            KeyEvent.VK_L, Login.class.toString(), firstFrame));
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.setOpaque(false);
      btnPanel.add(gotToLoginBtn);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JLabel label = new JLabel("Register", SwingConstants.CENTER);
      add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

}

class Login extends JPanel {

   public Login(FirstFrame firstFrame) {
      JButton gotToRegisterBtn = new JButton(new SwapCardAction("Register",
            KeyEvent.VK_R, Register.class.toString(), firstFrame));
      setBackground(new Color(150, 200, 255));
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(gotToRegisterBtn);
      btnPanel.setOpaque(false);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JLabel label = new JLabel("Login", SwingConstants.CENTER);
      add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

}
```

Comment: Yep you my friend is a day saver :D ... or should i say night saver (its 4:40 am here :P ) 

Thank you very much :)

Comment: just one more thing ... its not related ! ... but when the panel change (they dont have the same sizes) the `pack()` method doesnt Pack :D ... any idea or a reference would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can suggest would be to pass a reference to `FirstFrame` to the constructors of `Register` and `Login`; or add another [controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) and pass it to that controller.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did with the help of - @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - and the simple idea of - @Elliott Frisch - :

```
public class FirstFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


JPanel cards;

public FirstFrame() {
    initComponents();

    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

    cards.add(new Login(), "login");
    cards.add(new Register(this), "reg"); //Passing the FirstFrame instance here

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(cards);

    changeCard("login"); // Switching Cards

    setLocationByPlatform(true);

    setVisible(true);
}

public void changeCard(String cName){
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
    cl.show(cards, cName);

    pack();
}
}
```

as for Register Class :

```
public class Register extends javax.swing.JPanel {

FirstFrame firstf;

public Register(FirstFrame ff) {
    initComponents();
    firstf = ff;
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {                                         
    firstf.changeCard("login");

}     

}
```